# Issue with calendar api

Tags: android

I'm having a issue with calendar api:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView t1, t2, t3;
Calendar c;
int day, hour, minute;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t1);
    t2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t2);
    t3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t3);

    c=Calendar.getInstance();
    day=c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    hour=c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    minute=c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    t1.setText(Integer.toString(day));
    t2.setText(Integer.toString(hour));
    t3.setText(Integer.toString(minute));

}
```

This code should give me current day, hour and minutes in 3 textviews
but it give wrong values (only minutes is correct), why it doesn't work?

Comment: What wrong values?

Comment: comment here or edit the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran this code myself, and I don't see anything wrong. It was executed today, Tuesday, at 2:50PM:

[image]

The first `TextView` shows the value "3", which is the defined value of the constant `Calendar.TUESDAY`. (The first day of the week is defined to be Sunday, and the values range from 1 to 7.)

The second `TextView` shows the value "14". `HOUR_OF_DAY` uses 24-hour time, so 14 is the same as 2PM. If you want 12-hour time, use `Calendar.HOUR` instead (though note that noon and midnight are represented by "0", not "12").

The third `TextView` shows the value "50". Not much to say here; it was 2:50PM so the minutes are 50.

Comment: Yes i didn't now that the first day is defined to be sunday so day is value is correct but hour (in 24h format) is still wrong, it give me two hours earlier, i can't find the bug.

Comment: thank you very much I hadn't seen that the time zone was set to zero on the  android studio emulator!

Answer (score -1):

Your code is correct and there is no problem with it! And if you don't know is that  the `Calendar` in `java.utils` does not return Strings direct but a numerical representation `int` of the day for example if day of the Week is Sunday you will see `1`. So if you want the actual String You have to convert yourself. But if you want just `int` do nothing. Also if you use `c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);`  you will get Hours in `24 hours` system. If you want in `12 hours` system you will have to use `c.get(Calendar.HOUR);`*(remember in this method midnight and noon are 0 using this method)*. I am going to add one more method to change week days from `int` to strings like "Monday".
**Here is the how your full code should be:**

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

      TextView t1, t2, t3;
      Calendar c;
      int  hour, minute;
      String day;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t1);
     t2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t2);
     t3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t3);

     c=Calendar.getInstance();
     day= getDayOfWeek(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));                         
     hour=c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
     minute=c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

     t1.setText((day));
     t2.setText(Integer.toString(hour));
     t3.setText(Integer.toString(minute));

 private String getDayOfWeek(int value){
   String day = "";
   switch(value){
   case 1:
     day="Sunday";
     break;
   case 2:
     day="Monday";
     break;
   case 3:
     day="Tuesday";
     break;
   case 4:
     day="Wednesday";
     break;
   case 5:
     day="Thursday";
     break;
     case 6:
     day="Friday";
     break;
     case 7:
     day="Saturday";
     break;
   }
return day;
  }
}
```

I hope this will clear some misunderstandings in the `Calendar` in java! **Happy Coding!**